# Detect when tab was restored from history

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

How to detect when a tab was restored from history?

When a single tab is restored in `onCreated` event we can check `pendingUrl` property of the `tab`:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab =>
{
  console.log("restored", tab.pendingUrl && tab.pendingUrl === tab.url);
});
```

but in Edge v119.0.2151.58 this property not available when a window is restored and `onCreated` event fired for each tab in that window.

Comment: The `status` will be always(?) `complete` it seems in this scenario. So you can check like `tab.pendingUrl ? tab.pendingUrl === tab.url : tab.status === 'complete'`

Comment: Hmmm...in my tests it's never "complete"...when a window restored, it's "unloaded" and for a single tab it's "loading"

Comment: I tested in Chrome. Apparently it's browser-specific, so you'll have to add the check for browser in the condition.

Comment: Well, that's not good....I'm getting the same result in both Chrome 119.0.6045.124 and Edge 119.0.2151.58 (both with default settings)

Comment: Either via history panel, hotkey `CTRL+SHIFT+T` or via `chrome.sessions.restore()`. So I have a window with a few tabs, I close it and restore it with `CTRL+SHIFT+T`

Comment: It's `complete` for chrome-extension:// tabs and `unloaded` for web tabs.